# eliminitate double function name in firebase https function endpoint

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In my journey to get familiar with google cloud functions, I also try to find the 'best' way to organize my functions in a folder structure as well as the endpoint routing structure. I also want to apply the CORS functionality and prevent as many repeating code as possible. And I am almost satisfied with what I have reached, only one last issue is bugging me. The endpoints as I have it now, are now build up like this pattern:

```
https://<region>-<projectId>.cloudfunctions.net/<functionname1>/functionname2>
```

I have now 2 function names in my route and I haven't found a way yet to eliminate one function name. Out of the box, cloud functions only have 1 function name and the reason I am having 2 function names, got to do with applying CORS to the cloud functions. I am using express and the CORS middleware to do that.

In a single file, I configure my cors (applying whitelisting, handling errors):

```
const corsConfig = express();
corsConfig.use(cors({origin: originCheck })); //<-- function to apply whitelisting
corsConfig.use(handleCorsError); //<-- change the 500 error to a 403 error

export const app = corsConfig;
```

This module I use to add my functions with their endpoints:

test1.ts

```
import { app } from '../cors';

app.get('/test1', async (_request, response) => {
    response.send("test1");
});

export const test1 = functionsEUWest1.https.onRequest(app);
```

test2.ts

```
import { app } from '../cors';

app.get('/test2', async (_request, response) => {
    response.send("test2");
});

export const test2 = functionsEUWest1.https.onRequest(app);
```

Sidenote: functionsEUWest1 is to configure the region for where to deploy the functions.

Both the test files then are 'imported' (actually exported) in the index.ts which is used by the CLI to find and deploy the functions.

export * from './test1';
export * from './test2';

After deploying these functions, the firebase console shows only one functionname in the endpoint url (/test1) but when calling that endpoint, it returns the error:

> Cannot GET /
>   When calling with both the function names (/test1/test1) the text 'test1' is returned. The second /test1 is handled internally in the cloud function itself.

By using express, it is possible to add more endpoints to the cloud function endpoint and there is a way where for example the endpoints could look like this:

> /v1/test1
>   /v1/test2

But that would (propably) mean that all the functions are placed in one firebase cloud function. And I think this isn't the way to go due to logging and perhaps performance impact.

Has anyone faced the same situation and managed to find a way to eliminate a function name in the endpoint? Or am I completely on the wrong path with how I try to organize my code now?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do the the way you're organizing your code.  The URL that Cloud Functions assigns will always have the name of the top-level exported function as the first path component.  This is unavoidable.  Your Express route is then adding another path component.

If you want to customize the names of the paths, consider using Firebase Hosting as a caching proxy in front of Cloud Functions.  You can then use a URL rewrite to make the leading part of the path look any way you want.

Here's the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

Comment: I am familiar with this, I know that the const variable is the top level and that in the app.get or app.post, etc the second part of the path is, which is out of control of the firebase cloud. I also know that the first part is unavoidable but I try to find a way that the second part of the path isn't required so I don't need 2 names in my path (I call them function names, which propably generated some confusing, it could be any name of course). 

The link you gave states the solution you offer only works in the us-central region, I want to use the europe-west region.

Comment: Also, when I want to use the rewrite like suggested in the link, the source: ** is already used for the spa configuration of firebase in firebase.json and redirects to /index.html. So I didn't quite understand how that can work without conflicting situations.

Comment: Seems to me that you don't have any options, then, unless you wanted to migrate to Cloud Run.  Firebase Hosting will proxy to a region of your choice with that product.  You should file a feature request for multiple region support for proxy to Cloud Functions.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: okay, no problem. It is not the end of the world of course to have endpoints with 2 names. In the services of the client I want to add a function anyway that is concating the base url with the endpoint path and now I have to add an additional name. It looks a bit silly but if there is no other way, then so be it. Thank you for answering and thinking along.